# Authentication in Spring Web Security issue

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am going to set up background Spring Authentication by a custom class that implemented `UserDetailsService`. As said in the documentation method `loadUserByUsername` calls each time when user try to login, but it don't in the case below.

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<Person> personByUserName = personRepository.findPersonByUserName(username);

        Person person = personByUserName.
                orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User with username has not found"));

        return new User(username, person.getPassword(), Collections.emptyList());
    }

}
```

I try to use several alternatives to set up configure(HttpSecurity http) method in WebSecurityConfig class.

1. @Override
       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http.csrf().disable();

   ```
       http
               .authorizeRequests()
               .anyRequest().authenticated() 

               .and()
               .formLogin()
               .loginProcessingUrl("api/person/login") 
               .usernameParameter("username")
               .passwordParameter("password");
   }
   ```
2. @Override
       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http.csrf().disable();

   ```
       http
               .httpBasic()
               .and()
               .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/index.html", "/", "/home", "/api/person/login").permitAll()
               .anyRequest().authenticated();

   }
   ```
3. @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.csrf().disable();

   ```
               http.
               authorizeRequests().
               anyRequest().authenticated()
              .and().
               formLogin().
               loginProcessingUrl("/login").
               usernameParameter("username").
               passwordParameter("password");
   ```

   }

Registration DaoAuthenticationProvider:

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(getAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider getAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(authenticationUserDetailsService);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }
```

Could anyone explain, where is error, and why `loadUserByUsername` method doesn't call at all?

The Angular 8 UI part uses to login.

```
public loginPerson(person: Person): Observable<Person> {
    let url = "http://localhost:8080/login";
    return this.httpClient.post<Person>(url, {userName: person.username, password: person.password});
  }
```

Comment: You can autowire `authenticationuserDetailsService` and  pass it to auth manager as `@Override protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { auth.userDetailsService(authenticationuserDetailsService));
  }`

Comment: @Ritesh This part had included as well